# Prove that for any $A \neq 0$ there is a matrix $B$ such that $A + B$ and $B$ have no eigenvalues in common.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am not sure how to begin thinking about this problem.  Could anyone provide a push in the right direction, or an explanation of what are the first things that go through their head when solving this?

Let $A \neq 0$ be an $n \times n$ complex matrix. Prove there is a matrix $B$ such that $A + B$ and $B$ have no eigenvalues in common.

Comment: Hint: what are the eigenvalues of $A+cI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: @egreg Say $A$ is given by $a_{11} = 1$ and all other entries zero (with $n \geq 2$). Then $A + cI$ clearly has $c$ as an eigenvalue, as does $cI$. So in that case, $B = cI$ doesn't work for any $c$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is a  a multiple of $I_n$, then we may take $B=A$.
So suppose that $A$ is not a multiple of $I_n$.

Clearly the problem is invariant by conjugation (i.e. for any
invertible matrix $P$, $(A,B)$ satisfies the conditions iff $(P^{-1}AP,P^{-1}BP)$ does).

**Lemma.** If $A$ is not a multiple of $I_n$, then there is a conjugate
of $A$ whose lower leftmost coefficient is nonzero.

**Proof of lemma.**  We can assume that $A$ is in Jordan normal form. 
Since $A$ is not a multiple of $I_n$, either $A$ has at least two distinct eigenvalues or the form must have a one at
a nondiagonal position.

In the first case, suppose $Ae_{k}=\lambda_k e_k$ and $Ae_{l}=\lambda_le_l$ with $\lambda_k \neq \lambda_l$. In the initial basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$, replace $e_l$ with $e_k+e_l$, and then reordering so that $e_k$ is put first and $e_k+e_l$ is put last, we are done.

In the second case, suppose there is a $1$ at the intersection of the $i$-th column with the $j$-th row, with $i\neq j$. Reordering the initial basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ so that $e_i$ is put first and $e_j$ is put last,we are done.

So we can assume without loss of generality that $A$ has a nonzero
lower leftmost coefficient (let us call it $a$) :

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
a & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$
Now, consider the matrix all of whose terms are zero except on a pushed diagonal : 
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & b_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b_{n-1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then $B$ is nilpotent : its only eigenvalue is $0$.
On the other hand, the determinant of $A+B$ is a polynomial in $b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1}$,
and the coefficient in $b_1\ldots b_{n-1}$ is exactly $a$, which is a nonzero 
coefficient. So the polynomial is nonzero, and for a suitable choice
of $(b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1})$ its value will be nonzero. Then $A+B$ will be
invertible, solving your problem.

Comment: Very clever. Construct a matrix B with only zero eigenvalues, but A+B invertible.  Very cool, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can this be interpreted in terms of linear transformations? The purely matrix viewpoint is unenlightening to me.